# Loop stalling when deleting files

Tags: applescript

The script below is supposed to delete all files ending in .aux, etc.
in the current directory (i.e. directory displayed in the finder window)
The script seems to stall on deleting .aux files.
Any hint is welcome.

---

```
try

    tell application "Finder"

        set lieu to target of window 1

        set finale to {".aux", ".log", ".bak", ".out", ".synctex.gz"} as list

        repeat with x in finale

            try

                delete (every item of lieu whose name ends with x)

            end try

        end repeat

    end tell

    say "Mess cleaned up"

on error

    display dialog ("Error. Couldn't Delete the File") buttons {"OK"}

end try
```

Comment: Seems to work here. I don't think that the issue is related to a certain file extension. I assume it needs (much much) longer when the folder has many files in it.

Comment: I can confirm that it works for me, too, with a simple folder of only a few files in it. Have you tested it with only a couple of files? Under what circumstances does it fail? Does it ever succeed? For example, your script works just fine with a completely empty folder as well—is the same true on your end? Do some troubleshooting with multiple conditions—only a few files, no files, some extensions but not others if mere size isn’t the issue—and then report the results of your own troubleshooting.

Comment: Indeed, folder size seems to be the issue. Is there anyway I can optimize the code?
Would a posix rm *.aux e.g. accelerate the process?

Comment: Yes, a **for a in aux log bak out synctex.gz ; do rm *$a ; done** (UNTESTED) loop, in shell.  would be much better, what happens here, is that Finder is served more events that it can chew over, and it may go stale, or appear to be so. A first step may be to see if system events are capable though, if you **want** to use AppleScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a version that uses `rm`:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set lieu to target of window 1 as text
    set posixPathOfLieu to POSIX path of lieu
    set shellScript to "cd" & space & quoted form of posixPathOfLieu & ";rm *.aux *.log *.bak *.out *.synctex.gz"
    try
        do shell script shellScript
    end try
end tell
```

Please be *extremly careful* when using `rm`. One space character at the wrong place can delete everything.